# Large Lorentz Boost

Tags: special-relativity, terminology, inertial-frames

I understand the general concept of a lorentz transformation and a lorentz boost. What does it mean for a lorentz boost to be large however?

My current guess is that this is referring to a large difference in velocity between the frames of reference, is this accurate?

Comment: Yes, That’s right.

Comment: Large can mean two things depending on the context: (1) $\gamma-1$ is not negligible compared to $1$ (as answered below) or (2) $\gamma \gg 1$.

Answer (score 1):

How large is "large"? It depends on the context. Typically, a large Lorentz boost is one that produces relativistic deviations from what Newtonian mechanics predicts that are too large to be ignored.

Note that for $v=0.1c$, the Lorentz factor $\gamma \approx 1.005$, which is negligible for many purposes, so a large Lorentz boost needs to be larger than that.

Answer (score 0):

As PM 2Ring said, large depends on the context. A relative velocity of 0.5c can cause a phenomenon that lasts one 1 millisecond in one frame of reference to last for 1.15 millisecond in the other one due to time dilation. If you are working on a scale of microseconds, then this is a huge time difference. However, if you are working on a scale of seconds, then this negligible.

Just to give you a scale of what is possible in the Universe, the Lorentz factors deducted from observations in Active Galactic Nuclei (AGNs) are of the order of 50 to around 100. While for Gamma-Ray Bursts (GRBs), they are of the order of several hundred (usually 100 to around 400). But Lorentz factors of over 1000 have also been estimated for certain GRBs. For reference, a value of $\gamma=100$ corresponds to a relative velocity of 0.99995c between the frames of reference.

Formulae:

The time dilation formula is given by $$\Delta t= \gamma \Delta t'.$$ $\Delta t$ and $\Delta t'$ are the duration of the phenomena measured in each frame of reference.

Also, $$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},$$ where $v$ is the velocity and $c$ is the speed of light.